# Can i export models from Rapidminer (similar to Datarobot Prime)?

Tags: rapidminer

I have seen some automl tools being able to export the models (including the features) as an approximate model in python. For example Datarobot has Prime which is pretty cool.

Is this something we can do in Rapidminer as well ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I export RapidMiner model to integrate with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592608/can-i-export-rapidminer-model-to-integrate-with-python)

Comment: Although they sometimes have an export of certain model types in Rapidminer, it won't be a super-fast rules-based approximation like you get from *DataRobot Prime*.

Answer (score 1):

you have several options here, depending  on your actual use case:

In RapidMiner you can store any model in your repository and run it on any other RapidMiner instance with the generic *Apply Model* Operator.

For most of the models you can use the [pmml extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_pmml) to export it in a common format.

If you are interested in the parameters and the description of the models, the [converters extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_converters) has operators to transform a model into an example set.